# LINQ operation on an IQueryable that joins to another IQueryable that needs to be group byed?

Tags: c#, linq

Consider three IQueryables: tableA, tableB, and tableC. 
They all have a composite key of 3 values, a, b, and c.
I will need to get a sum amount of a column in tableB, d,  partitioned by a, b, and c. How do I join the three tables together to get an accurate partition to select a new object? My compiler always shows an error.

here is my basic query that I have tried:

```
from A in tableA
join B in tableB on new { A.a, A.b, A.c } equals new { B.a, B.b, B.c } into p1
group B by new  { B.a, B.b, B.c } into p2

from q2 in p2
join C in tableC on new { A.a, A.b, A.c }  equals new { C.a, C.b, C.c }  into p3

from results in p3
select new NewObject
{
    Column1 = p3.A.a,
    Column2 = p3.A.b,
    Column3 = p3.A.c,
    Column4 = Sum(p3.C.d),
    Column5 = p3.B.e
};
```

I get this long error about ambiguous invocation and I get red lines all over the place. I guess I'm not too sure how to do multiple joins onto a group by'd IQueryable. Is that even possible?

Comment: Please add the error message you mentioned.

Comment: You already do a group join into p1, so do you need the group by into p2 at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this scenario, your query could benefit by simplifying the joins, writing a select with all of the required columns, and then utilizing the fluent API as follows. I believe this query will achieve your desired result.

```
var model = (from A in tableA
             join B in tableB on new { A.a, A.b, A.c } equals new { B.a, B.b, B.c }
             join C in tableC on new { A.a, A.b, A.c }  equals new { C.a, C.b, C.c }
             select new {
                 Aa = A.a,
                 Ab = A.b,
                 Ac = A.c,
                 Ba = B.a,
                 Bb = B.b,
                 Bc = B.c,
                 Be = B.e,
                 Ca = C.a,
                 Cb = C.b,
                 Cc = C.c,
                 Cd = C.d
             })
             .GroupBy(x => new {x.Ba, x.Bb, x.Bc})
             .Select(grp => new {
                 Column1 = grp.First().Aa,
                 Column2 = grp.First().Ab,
                 Column3 = grp.First().Ac,
                 Column4 = grp.Sum(y => y.Cd),
                 Column5 = grp.First().Be
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: This is a good start! However, now I'm seeing "Cannot resolve symbol..." for Ab, Ac, and SelectMany is underlined in red with "The type arguments can not be inferred from the usage." Any suggestions?

Everything else looks beautiful!

Comment: I've edited my answer above. Changing the SelectMany to a Select combined with the First() operator should resolve your errors, however you'll likely still need to alter your query to ensure you're getting the correct results.

Comment: This helped greatly. Thank you.